# Given i.i.d. X,Y, $P(|X-Y|<\epsilon)=1$ then it is a degenerate distribution, why?

Tags: probability

Given two i.i.d. random variables X, Y, if $P(|X-Y|<\epsilon)=1, \forall \epsilon>0$, then $P(X=C)=1$ for some constance $C$. How to prove it?

Comment: you mean $P(|X - Y| < \epsilon) = 1$?

Comment: Yes! I mean '=1' and have edited.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $P(|X-Y|< \epsilon)=1$ for all $\epsilon$, then I suggest the following: Argue by contradiction. If $P(X=C)<1$ for all $C$, then there must exist two, disjoint intervals $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ so that $P(X \in (a,b)) >0$ and $P(X \in (c,d)) >0$ (why?). It follows from the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are iid that $P((X,Y) \in (a,b)\times(c,d))>0$. Note that for any events $A$ and $B$ with $P(A)=1$, $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$ (check by taking the complement of $A\cap B$). It follows from the assumption $P(|X-Y|< \epsilon)=1$ that $P(\{(X,Y) \in (a,b)\times(c,d)\} \cap \{|X-Y|<1/n\})>0$ for all $n$. Eventually $\{(X,Y) \in (a,b)\times(c,d)\} \cap \{|X-Y|<1/n\}$ is empty though.

Comment: Thanks so much! What if $b=c$? And $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are still disjoint.

Comment: Good point.  But you can prove there is a positive distance between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d):$ that is the crux of the matter. Perhaps a clearer way to frame it is to prove there exist numbers $a$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$ for which $p_1=\Pr(X\lt a-\epsilon/2)\gt 0$ and $p_2=\Pr(X\gt a+\epsilon/2)\gt 0.$ Independence implies $\Pr(|X-Y|\lt \epsilon)\le 1-2p_1p_2 \lt 1,$ which is the desired contradiction.